# how to delete row in uitableview when click on button

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi i am implementing a table in which i am getting  request i have list of students to which i want to add as my room mate  i have two button accept and reject the problem is here when i click on accept button i want that row will be deleted from the array and also i want to shift the deleted row value into the table of nextview controller in case of accept request . and in case of reject button cliked only want to delete the row not to move the value of cell into next view controller  i am implementing this project by using storyboard can anybody have idea about that plase share me  this is the code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"DefaultCell"];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell =[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"DefaultCell"];

    }
    acceptreq = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    acceptreq.frame =CGRectMake(170, 10, 60, 30);
    rejectreq = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    rejectreq.frame =CGRectMake(240, 10, 60, 30);
    [acceptreq setTitle:@"Accept" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rejectreq setTitle:@"Reject" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [acceptreq addTarget:self action:@selector(Acceptrequest:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [rejectreq addTarget:self action:@selector(Rejectrequest:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell addSubview:acceptreq];
    [cell addSubview:rejectreq];
    [acceptreq setTag:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [myarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Please accept answers in your previous questions and improve accpet rate. It will encourage people to help you. =)

Comment: Delete element from data source and call reload

Comment: English 100 - End each sentence with a period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short you can delete selected Row with clicking `UIbutton` like bellow:-

```
-(IBAction)Acceptrequest:(id)sender
{
UIButton *btn =(UIButton*)sender;

[myarray removeObjectsAtIndexes:btn.tag];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:myarray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

[tableVIew reloadData];
}
```

Comment: getting this error /Users/mobitsolutions/Desktop/adnan/BedSpace/RequestViewController.m:64:6: No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'removeObjectsAtIndexes:' on this line [myarray removeObjectsAtIndexes:btn.tag];

Comment: myarray = [NSMutableArray array]

Comment: another error when click on button i just now declare array as nsmutablearray but when click on button getting this error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a120'

Comment: I suggest you to go to iOS documentation and read more about use of arrays. The flow is simple: you add to array A the index paths you want to delete, then in tableview you remove those rows. In array B (datasource) you remove the index.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this method:

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:arrayOfIndexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Comment: It has to be NSMutableArray instead of NSArray